# How to get the fitted values from a model run with R package MICE

Tags: r, r-mice

I have written a GLMM with eight fixed effects and two random effects. Two of my fixed effects contained missing data, so I used the R package MICE to impute the missing values.

I want to create a graph with the fitted values from my model and the actual observed values. If I didn't have missing data and had used the package lme4 to run my model, I would simply use the function fitted() to get the model’s fitted values. However, because I used MICE, I am unsure how to get the fitted values for my model. When I use the function fitted(), it returns “NULL” instead of a vector of the fitted values.

I've been scouring the internet to try and find an example where someone else has gotten a vector of the fitted values after using MICE to impute missing data and run a GLMM, but I have not been able to find anything...

Does anyone know of the function or a way to calculate the fitted values from my model that was run using the MICE package? Or possibly recommend another resource that could help?

Many thanks in advance,
Olivia

Answer (score 2):

Without a working example it is hard to figure out what exactly you run into.

Nevertheless here is an example using `mice` and `lme4` packages fitting a (nonsense) model with `lmer`.

```
require(mice)
require(lme4)

dt <- mice(nhanes2, seed = 314)

mod <- with(dt, lme4::lmer(bmi ~ chl + (1 | hyp)))

summary(pool(mod))
```

gives:

```
Class: mipo    m = 5 
               estimate         ubar            b            t dfcom       df       riv    lambda       fmi
(Intercept) 21.74573850 14.857649384 2.799244e+00 1.821674e+01    21 13.85172 0.2260850 0.1843959 0.2811936
chl          0.02574043  0.000379629 7.879048e-05 4.741775e-04    21 13.36442 0.2490552 0.1993949 0.2972420
```

Fit the model in a list column and extract the fitted values for each imputation set. Then take the mean of the fitted values, as a way to pool these fitted values. I am not sure if this is the recommended way of pooling fitted values, though. 
See also: https://github.com/stefvanbuuren/mice/issues/82 for some expert advice.

```
dt %>%
  mice::complete(action = "long", include = FALSE) %>%
  group_by(.imp) %>%
  nest(.key = dt) %>%
  mutate(mod = map(dt, ~ lmer(formula =  bmi ~ chl + (1 | hyp), data = .x))) %>%
  mutate(fitted = map(mod, ~ data.frame(fitted = fitted(.x), id = seq_along(fitted(.x))))) %>%
  select(.imp, fitted) %>%
  unnest() %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(fitted = mean(fitted))
```

gives:

```
# A tibble: 25 x 2
      id fitted
   <int>  <dbl>
 1     1   27.1
 2     2   26.6
 3     3   26.6
 4     4   27.1
 5     5   24.7
 6     6   26.5
 7     7   24.8
 8     8   26.6
 9     9   27.9
10    10   27.0
# ... with 15 more rows
```

Comment: Hi Wietze,
Apologies if my original post wasn’t clear enough. Your response is exactly the method I have used for the model. However, what I’m looking to do is get the fitted values from my model, so I can later graph them with the actual observed values.
For example, if I ran a model using lmer() from the package lme4, I could use the function fitted() to get these values. I’m looking for something similar to fitted() that will work with my model that I’ve run using the with() function from MICE.
Hopefully this helps clarify my question…
Many thanks, Olivia

Comment: I think you first have to research how to `pool` these fitted values. But by simply taking the mean, I have added a solution to my example.

Comment: Thanks, that’s helpful
I’ve read one shouldn’t take the means across the imputed datasets (see https://stefvanbuuren.name/fimd/sec-limitations.html , starting with section 12.1.3), so I’ll have to keep digging. There must be a way to extract fitted values after using the function pool()... Cheers, Olivia

Comment: If you mean you want to apply the pooled estimates to your data, it would be possible to just use the estimates on your data. However that would be similar to taking the means across datasets and ignoring the imputation variance. 
As @jay.sf put in his answer you could also plot all predicitons of every imputed dataset. 
I think it is better to find a way in which you can quantify the uncertainty of the predictions, as you would do with pooling estimates.

Answer (score 1):

The uncertainity of the MICE-imputation method is expressed by multiple produced imputation data sets. Calculations as regressions need to be pooled with "Rubin's rule". AFAIK just simple `lm` or `glm` methods are implemented into the `mice::pool(.)` method. You probably need to write some code yourself to pool e.g. the calculations of random effects as you probably do with `lme4`. You may find the needed formulae in **Rubin, Donald B. Multiple Imputation for Nonresponse in Surveys. Wiley Series in Probability and Mathematical Statistics. New York: Wiley, 1987** on page **76**.

However, if your model is not that complicated you could combine the fitted values of the different imputations in one plot and separate them with colors.

#### Example 1

```
library(mice)
iris.mice <- complete(mice(iris.mis), "long")
with(iris.mice, plot(Petal.Length, lm(Petal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Width)$fitted,
                     type="n", xlab="imp.actual", ylab="imp.yhat", main="Petal.Length"))
by(iris.mice, iris.mice$.imp, function(x) {
  with(x, points(Petal.Length, lm(Petal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Width, x)$fitted,
                 col=x$.imp))
})
legend("bottomright", legend=unique(iris.mice$.imp), pch=1, col=unique(iris.mice$.imp),
       ncol=3, title="Imp.")
```

[image]

Another possibility would be to use a different imputation method, e.g., MissForest, which produces just one imputed data set with an error margin. It probably would be much easier to do calculations of more complicated models w/o needing to pool everything, depends on what you need, though. You could report the error margin in the plot as text.

#### Example 2

```
library(missForest)
iris.imp <- missForest(iris.mis, xtrue=iris)
with(iris.imp$ximp, plot(Petal.Length, 
                         lm(Petal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Width)$fitted,
                         xlab="imp.actual", ylab="imp.yhat", main="Petal.Length"))
text(5.5, 1.7, paste("NRMSE=", round(iris.imp$error[1], 2)))
```

[image]

#### Data

```
iris.mis <- structure(list(Sepal.Length = c(5.1, NA, 4.7, 4.6, NA, 5.4, 4.6, 
5, 4.4, 4.9, 5.4, 4.8, 4.8, 4.3, 5.8, 5.7, 5.4, 5.1, 5.7, 5.1, 
5.4, 5.1, 4.6, NA, 4.8, 5, 5, 5.2, 5.2, 4.7, 4.8, 5.4, NA, NA, 
4.9, NA, NA, 4.9, 4.4, 5.1, 5, 4.5, 4.4, 5, 5.1, 4.8, 5.1, 4.6, 
5.3, 5, 7, 6.4, 6.9, 5.5, NA, 5.7, 6.3, 4.9, 6.6, 5.2, 5, 5.9, 
6, 6.1, 5.6, 6.7, 5.6, 5.8, 6.2, 5.6, 5.9, 6.1, NA, 6.1, 6.4, 
6.6, 6.8, 6.7, 6, 5.7, 5.5, 5.5, 5.8, NA, 5.4, 6, 6.7, NA, 5.6, 
5.5, 5.5, 6.1, 5.8, NA, 5.6, 5.7, NA, 6.2, 5.1, NA, 6.3, NA, 
7.1, 6.3, 6.5, 7.6, 4.9, 7.3, 6.7, NA, 6.5, NA, 6.8, 5.7, 5.8, 
6.4, 6.5, 7.7, 7.7, 6, 6.9, 5.6, 7.7, 6.3, 6.7, 7.2, 6.2, 6.1, 
NA, 7.2, NA, 7.9, 6.4, 6.3, 6.1, 7.7, 6.3, NA, NA, 6.9, 6.7, 
6.9, 5.8, 6.8, 6.7, NA, NA, 6.5, 6.2, NA), Sepal.Width = c(3.5, 
3, 3.2, NA, 3.6, 3.9, 3.4, 3.4, NA, 3.1, 3.7, NA, NA, 3, NA, 
4.4, 3.9, 3.5, 3.8, 3.8, 3.4, NA, 3.6, 3.3, 3.4, 3, 3.4, 3.5, 
3.4, 3.2, 3.1, NA, 4.1, 4.2, 3.1, NA, 3.5, 3.6, 3, NA, 3.5, 2.3, 
3.2, NA, 3.8, NA, 3.8, NA, 3.7, 3.3, 3.2, NA, NA, 2.3, NA, 2.8, 
3.3, NA, 2.9, 2.7, 2, 3, 2.2, 2.9, 2.9, 3.1, 3, NA, 2.2, 2.5, 
3.2, NA, NA, 2.8, 2.9, 3, NA, NA, 2.9, 2.6, 2.4, 2.4, NA, 2.7, 
3, 3.4, 3.1, 2.3, 3, 2.5, NA, NA, 2.6, 2.3, 2.7, NA, 2.9, 2.9, 
2.5, 2.8, 3.3, 2.7, 3, 2.9, 3, 3, 2.5, 2.9, 2.5, 3.6, 3.2, 2.7, 
3, 2.5, NA, NA, 3, 3.8, 2.6, NA, 3.2, 2.8, 2.8, 2.7, 3.3, 3.2, 
2.8, 3, 2.8, 3, 2.8, 3.8, NA, 2.8, 2.6, NA, 3.4, 3.1, 3, 3.1, 
3.1, 3.1, 2.7, 3.2, 3.3, 3, NA, 3, NA, 3), Petal.Length = c(NA, 
1.4, NA, NA, 1.4, 1.7, 1.4, 1.5, NA, 1.5, 1.5, 1.6, NA, 1.1, 
1.2, 1.5, 1.3, 1.4, 1.7, 1.5, 1.7, 1.5, 1, 1.7, NA, 1.6, NA, 
1.5, NA, 1.6, 1.6, NA, 1.5, 1.4, 1.5, NA, NA, NA, 1.3, 1.5, 1.3, 
1.3, NA, 1.6, 1.9, 1.4, 1.6, 1.4, 1.5, 1.4, NA, 4.5, 4.9, 4, 
4.6, 4.5, NA, 3.3, 4.6, 3.9, NA, NA, 4, 4.7, 3.6, NA, 4.5, 4.1, 
4.5, 3.9, 4.8, 4, NA, NA, 4.3, 4.4, 4.8, 5, 4.5, 3.5, NA, 3.7, 
3.9, 5.1, NA, 4.5, NA, 4.4, 4.1, 4, 4.4, 4.6, NA, 3.3, 4.2, 4.2, 
4.2, 4.3, NA, NA, 6, 5.1, 5.9, NA, 5.8, 6.6, 4.5, 6.3, NA, 6.1, 
5.1, NA, 5.5, 5, 5.1, 5.3, 5.5, 6.7, 6.9, 5, 5.7, 4.9, 6.7, 4.9, 
5.7, 6, 4.8, 4.9, 5.6, 5.8, NA, 6.4, 5.6, 5.1, 5.6, 6.1, 5.6, 
5.5, 4.8, NA, NA, 5.1, NA, 5.9, 5.7, 5.2, 5, 5.2, 5.4, 5.1), 
    Petal.Width = c(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, NA, 0.3, 0.2, NA, 
    0.1, 0.2, NA, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.4, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 
    0.4, 0.2, NA, 0.2, NA, 0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, NA, 
    0.2, 0.2, NA, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, NA, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.6, 0.4, 
    0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, NA, 1.5, 1.5, NA, 1.5, 1.3, NA, 
    1, 1.3, 1.4, 1, 1.5, 1, NA, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1, 1.5, 1.1, NA, 
    NA, 1.5, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.4, NA, 1.5, NA, NA, 1, 1.2, NA, 
    1.5, 1.6, 1.5, 1.3, 1.3, NA, 1.2, NA, NA, 1, 1.3, 1.2, 1.3, 
    1.3, 1.1, 1.3, 2.5, NA, 2.1, 1.8, 2.2, 2.1, 1.7, NA, 1.8, 
    NA, 2, 1.9, 2.1, 2, 2.4, 2.3, NA, NA, 2.3, 1.5, 2.3, 2, 2, 
    1.8, NA, 1.8, 1.8, NA, 2.1, NA, 1.9, 2, 2.2, 1.5, 1.4, 2.3, 
    2.4, 1.8, 1.8, 2.1, 2.4, 2.3, NA, 2.3, 2.5, 2.3, 1.9, NA, 
    NA, 1.8), Species = structure(c(1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, NA, 
    2L, 2L, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, NA, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, NA, 
    NA, 2L, 2L, 3L, NA, NA, NA, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, NA, 3L, NA, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, NA, 3L, NA, 
    3L, 3L, NA, 3L, NA, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, NA, 3L, 3L, 3L, NA, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("setosa", "versicolor", 
    "virginica"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -150L
), class = "data.frame")
```